# VISUALFORCE - Sort Opportunity line items as they are displayed

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, opportunity-lineitem

I have a visual force page that uses the apex:repeat to loop through the Opportunity line items. But the order is not as it displayed in the Opportunity. I can check the SortOrder value of the line item, but this value is updated only when the user clicks the "Sort" button.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to get items as they are displayed in the opp?
2. If not, can I trigger the SortOrder  value to be updated without the sort button?

   ```
    var ProductsArr  = new Array();

   <apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems}" var="lineitem">

   var product_row  = {name:"{!lineitem.product2.name}", quantity:{!lineitem.quantity}, ID:{!lineitem.product2.Hasavshevet_product_ID__c},price:{!lineitem.UnitPrice}};

   console.log("{!lineitem.SortOrder}");

   ProductsArr.push(product_row);

   </apex:repeat>
   ```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the only solution was to get the products with an APEX controller.

```
this.allLineItems=new List<OpportunityLineItem>([select 
id,UnitPrice,Product2.Name,Quantity,Product2.Hasavshevet_product_ID__c 
from OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId = :Opp.id ORDER BY SortOrder]);  

this.userinput = this.allLineItems[0].Product2.Name;

    m_names = new List<String>();
    m_ids = new List<Decimal>();
    m_price = new List<Decimal>();
    m_quan = new List<Decimal>();

    for (OpportunityLineItem item : this.allLineItems) {
        m_names.add(item.Product2.Name);
        m_quan.add(item.Quantity);
        m_price.add(item.UnitPrice);
        if(item.Product2.Hasavshevet_product_ID__c != null)
            m_ids.add(item.Product2.Hasavshevet_product_ID__c);
        else
            m_ids.add(321);
    }

    JSON_NAMES = JSON.serialize(m_names);
```

These 4 arrays were initlized by the apex controller

```
public List<Decimal> m_quan    {get;set;}
public List<Decimal> m_price    {get;set;}
public List<Decimal> m_ids    {get;set;}
public String JSON_NAMES {get;set;}
```

And were later retrieved by the VF page:

```
for (var index = 0; index < arrayLength;index++) 
    {
        var product_row  = {name:{!JSON_NAMES}[index], quantity:{!m_quan}[index], ID:{!m_ids}[index],price: {!m_price}[index]};
        ProductsArr.push(product_row);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The SortOrder field is available, just not updateable. To get the sort order, include it in your script:

```
var product_row  = {sortOrder: {!BLANKVALUE(lineItem.SortOrder,0)}, name:"{!lineitem.product2.name}", quantity:{!lineitem.quantity}, ID:{!lineitem.product2.Hasavshevet_product_ID__c},price:{!lineitem.UnitPrice}};
```

Which you can then sort when you're done:

```
ProductsArr.sort((a,b) => a.sortOrder-b.sortOrder);
```

Comment: if the user did not click the sort button, the value is null.

Comment: @DavidSomekh Good point, I'll edit in a fix.

Comment: thx - but what i want is that if the user did not click "sort", i will get the order as displayed in the UI.

Comment: @DavidSomekh The sort order should be, I believe, by order of creation date, which is the same output I'd expect to see in `apex:repeat`. If it's not coming out that way, try adding CreatedDate to your object and sorting by that, instead.

Comment: Tried the approach with the created date, but it does not always help as multiple line items can be added at the same time. Also an opp can be cloned, and then all the line items have the same datetime.

Comment: @DavidSomekh Try sorting by Id, then?

Comment: Had the same problem. It seems sorting by `Id` does the trick.